# Regex Validation not triggering an Error in Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I want my RestController to return an error when the input of date is set(required = false) but with the wrong regex(f. e. 10-2019)

```
  @GetMapping
  @Timed
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyWrapper<List<ListData>>> getList(
     @RequestParam(name = "date", required = false) @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}") String date) {
    // Logic
  }
```

However, the validation isnt taking place. I was expecting an error but none was thrown, the error occured later, when i tried to build a new Object with the wrong input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Fix the validation with `@Validated`

When you want the validation to be triggered, the controller class must be annotated with [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html):

```java
@Validated
@RestController
public class MyController {
   ...
}
```

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation):

> To be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation.

### Don't use `@Timed`

I find it weird the fact your controller method is annotated with [`@Timed`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Timed.html). This is a **test-specific annotation** and it's not meant to be used in the actual code:

> Test-specific annotation to indicate that a test method has to finish execution in a specified time period.

You may also want to review your dependencies and ensure they use the correct scope.

### Consider `YearMonth` instead of `String`

As you seem to be receiving a year and month value in your controller method, it's better to use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) instead of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html):

> A year-month in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as `2007-12`.

Your controller method can be like:

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Foo> getList(@RequestParam(name = "date", required = false) YearMonth date) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you `@Validated` worked

We are not using org.springframework.test.annotation@Timed for testing we are using  io.micrometer.core.annotation@Timed for our Grafana

Thank you very much, we are now using `YearMonth` instead of `String`, this way it is way more reliable and reusable. Only thing, because we don't use ISO-Standard we had to implement an Pattern Converter with Regex: `^(\\d{4})-(1[0-2]|[1-9]|0[1-9])$`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the @Validated annotation to the class:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class myRestController{

@Timed
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyWrapper<List<ListData>>> getList(
     @RequestParam(name = "date", required = false) @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}") String date) {
    // Logic
  }
}
```

References: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints
point 3.

Comment: Does not work for me unfortunatelly, still same behavior

Comment: Do you have your controller class annotated as ```@Validated``` ?

Can you try with this change? As I edited on my Answer, you don't need ```@Valid``` annotation if you are using @Validated on the class

Comment: Yes thank you, that was the problem, forgot the @Validated annotation